# Java DateFormat issue on Mac vs Windows

Tags: java, date-format

I am using the code below on Mac OSX 10.10.2 and it's behaving strangely.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class StringToDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String dateInString = "23/Oct/2015";
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/YYYY");
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

---

Output on Mac:         `Sun Dec 28 00:00:00 CST 2014`

Output on Windows: `Fri Oct 23 00:00:00 CDT 2015`

---

Why is the Mac output wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`Y` is for the week year. Use `y` for the year.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
```

Also, make sure the DateFormat's locale is the right one.

EDIT:

A Date has millisecond precision, so if you want nanosecond precision, you shouldn't use Date and SimpleDateFormat.

S is for milliseconds. Since you tell SimpleDateFormat that the last part of the string is milliseconds, it parses it as that: 545000000 milliseconds (i.e. a bit more than 6 days, which explains the difference between the input and the output).

To get an accurate result, to the millisecond, remove the last 6 characters of the string, and use the pattern "dd-MMM-yyyy-HH.mm.ss.SSS".

Comment: No idea. Maybe not the same JDK version.

Comment: As I understand it week year should differ from year only when dealing with a date that is on the start/end boundary of the year, which isn't the case here. So while I agree the code should use "yyyy", how does this explain the result?

Comment: To be fair, I don't know. I'm not sure week years are even supposed to be parsed. It seems that as soon as a week year is found, the date is parsed as the first day of this week year.

Comment: I tried "YYYY" and "yyyy" results are same.. My exact date format is

String dateInString = "23-Oct-2013-16.38.51.545000000";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS");  
In this case its even weird it gives this output
"Wed Oct 30 00:02:11 CDT 2013" on Mac :) ... windows all good.

Not sure if am doing some incorrect mapping. I want the nano precisions as well from the String date. Should we really suspect JDK for such simple conversions? I tried jdk7 and 8 on mac, no difference. And windows has jdk 7.

Comment: @JBNizet  I appreciate your help. I changed as suggested it's giving correct results.